# Anagram chains - What is the common property in each?

Tags: anagram

This puzzle is about solving **anagram-chains**.

To start, let's first define what an **anagram-chain** is:

> - An **anagram-chain** consists of multiple anagrams stitched together into a long letter-list.
> - Each anagram of the chain (except the last) partly overlaps with the follow-up anagram, so that there are letters which are shared by *two* anagrams (but never more).
> - The *minimum* of letters which overlap is defined. i.e. an anagram chain of *overlap 3* (O3) requires that two anagrams overlap by *at least* 3 common letters.
> - No two anagrams overlap ever completely, i.e. no anagram can be 'fully' contained in another.
> - All anagrams of a chain share a **common theme** which is given.
> - All anagrams of a chain share a **common property** which needs to be found.

And now clarify this with an example:

> The following anagram-chain (*O3*) is themed ***presidents of the USA***:
>
> `IMMCARTRJYEFKEOHNNNDLBJOOYSNHRTRUARMAKBAABCOILLLINTN`

And it solves to:

> [image]

The common property is

> All are from the *Democratic* party.

---

## Can you now solve the following anagram chains:

> #### #1 *Night sky* (O2)
>
> `VNSEUCRYMRASNUURJPITEHARSTUNEPNE`
> Common property: ?

---

> #### #2 *Animals* (O3)
>
> `OSQUOMITEERTHONYBEEENPDCTIERCKCOCOAHGSSPRPERCALATILFFRUYTELEEBMBEUBLADYGONRFLVISHSIE`
> Common property: ?

---

> #### #3 *Food!* (O3)
>
> `RRTCAOVADOCHIRICUFLOWALEPTGGNIERTOKACHSPINTUROSPSAAUARGLICOOBRCUMUCETLTELNISPPARCES`
> Common property: ?

---

> #### #4 *Hollywood!* (O5)
>
> `KRIHPURNATHANEEBCLCTTOLETAUDEEBRPYHURNLOLHTEBOSIRYHWLAANKGCNEDJSOFIOTERSSGMNINOEICLKDASBNRAULOJOINEMEHLRRENIUISAEJBLRORTMCOIAINLADPEGEREGSRARONHZTHCLIEEJGSSAANBRBRRTEIADKNEAONWDJWOODARNCAFRJRENEENIELWKATSTHYBAEZTOLIETALRMEMANTMHOPSOIALREN`
> Common property: ?

Comment: I don't understand the overlap criterion. In your example, surely Obama and Clinton only overlap by 1 letter?

Comment: Never mind, I just realised the gaps are only there because of the extra |s in the first line. Maybe you should insert spaces or something?

Comment: In the first one, I think it should be VNSEUCRYMRASNTURJPITEHARSTUNEPNE not VNSEUCRYMRASNUURJPITEHARSTUNEPNE.

Comment: @randal'thor Currently travelling this week and will check later. I think, however, that something is indeed a bit odd (sorry). Shouldn't have posted that at 2.30am after a long day, I guess... I'll correct/edit when I get the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### First one

> ```
> VNSEUCRYMRASNtURJPITEHARSTUNEPNE
> VENUS   MARS  JUPITER SATURN
>    MERCURYSATURN   EARTH NEPTUNE
> ```

Note also the almost-possibility of

> ```
> VNSEUCRYMRASNtURJPITEHARSTUNEPNE
> VENUS   MARS  JUPITER STAR
>    MERCURYSATURN   EARTH NEPTUNE
> ```

Getting the same thing coming up twice is OK, but an overlap of less than 2 isn't! The common property is:

> **planets**.

The only problem is I think it should be VNSEUCRYMRASN**T**URJPITEHARSTUNEPNE not VNSEUCRYMRASNUURJPITEHARSTUNEPNE.

### Second one

> ```
> OSQUOMITEERTHONYBEEENPDCTIERCKCOCOAHGSSPRPERCALATILFFRUYTELEEBMBEUBLADYGONRFLVISHSIE
> MOSQUITO HORNET  CENTIPEDE COCKROACH    CATERPILLAR  BUTTERFLY   LADYBUG  SILVERFISH
>      TERMITEHONEYBEE   CRICKET   GRASSHOPPER    FRUITFLY   BUMBLEBEEDRAGONFLY
> ```

Common property:

> **insects/creepy-crawlies** (does the word **bugs** cover both of these?).

There seems to be something wrong in the middle, because where I've written BUTTERFLY doesn't quite match; there could be BEETLE on the right, but then nothing seems to fit the left! BmyGuest, please can you check this very carefully?

### Third one

> ```
> RRTCAOVADOCHIRICUFLOWALEPTGGNIERTOKACHSPINTUROSPSAAUARGLICOOBRCUMUCETLTELNISPPARCES
> CARROT RADICCHIO     EGGPLANTARTICHOKE TURNIP ASPARAGUSBROCCOLI  LETTUCE PARSNIP
>    AVOCADO   CAULIFLOWER  GINGER   SPINACHSPROUT    GARLIC  CUCUMBER LENTILS CAPERS
> ```

... but there's only a two-letter overlap between SPROUT and ASPARAGUS! The common property is:

> **vegetables**.

Comment: Preformatted text in spoilers is still visible for some reason - you can't change it (I think), I just wanted to let you know.

Comment: @mdc32 Thanks. On my screen at least it comes out as white on pale grey (as opposed to the usual white on white), which is still pretty hard to read. I couldn't come up with a better way of formatting it, since I really need a fixed-width font!

Comment: Regarding the second one, is a smaller-than-normal fruit fly a "fruit flylet"? Oh, and your "common property" is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Given that [rand al'thor, got #1, #2 & #3 above](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/10403/5208), I just focused on **#4**, which is:

> ```
> KRIHPURNATHANEEBCLCTTOLETAUDEEBRPYHURNLOLHTEBOSIRYHWLAANKGCNEDJSOFIOTERSSGMNINOEICLKDASBNRAULOJOINEMEHLRRENIUISAEJBLRORTMCOIAINLADPEGEREGSRARONHZTHCLIEEJGSSAANBRBRRTEIADKNEAONWDJWOODARNCAFRJRENEENIELWKATSTHYBAEZTOLIETALRMEMANTMHOPSOIALREN
> ```
>
> ```
> KATHARINEHEPBURNCLAUDETTECOLBERT HOLLYHUNTER  HILARYSWANK   JODIEFOSTER   NICOLEKIDMAN  JULIANNEMOORE LUISERAINER  MARIONCOTILLARD  GREERGARSON    JESSICALANGE     DIANEKEATON   JOANCRAWFORD    KATEWINSLETELIZABETHTAYLOREMMATHOMPSON
> ```
>
> ```
>         CATEBLANCHETT    AUDREYHEPBURN SHIRLEYBOOTH GLENDAJACKSON SIMONESIGNORET SANDRABULLOCK  HELENMIRREN JULIAROBERTS    GERALDINEPAGE CHARLIZETHERON  BARBRASTREISAND JOANNEWOODWARDJENNIFERLAWRENCEKATHYBATES   MARLEEMATLIN  SOPHIALOREN
> ```

Common property:

> ["Best Actress" Oscar winners](http://www.imdb.com/search/name?groups=oscar_best_actress_winners)

<sub>Sorry about the bad formatting... not sure how to have a multi-line, fixed-width font, non-wrapping, spoiler block...</sub>

Comment: Correct. Now i need to decide which answer to accept...

Comment: @BmyGuest - give it to rand, he got 3/4 (vs my 1) and I'm sure he would've got this one with time too. Nice puzzle btw. :)

Comment: What an honest user. I wish everyone was like this.